# Why is the child column component of AgGridReact not rendering?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

When rendering a AG grid table using external functional components for the declarative column definitions they don't get rendered. Also the columns component render is not executed when putting a breakpoint.

I have the following AG grid **table** component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import 'ag-grid-enterprise';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';
import Columns from '../columns/columns';

const Table = (props) => {
  const [columnDefs, setColumnDefs] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/api/grid/getDataOverviewGrid')
      .then((result) => {
        return result.json();
      })
      .then((gridOverview) => {
        setColumnDefs(gridOverview.data.gridColumns);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="ag-theme-alpine">
      <AgGridReact
        getDataPath={(data) => data.orgHierarchie}
        pagination={true}
        onGridReady={(params) => {
          fetch('/api/grid/getDataOverviewGridRows')
            .then((result) => {
              return result.json();
            })
            .then((rowData) => {
              params.api.setRowData(rowData.data);
            });
        }}
      >
        <Columns columnDefs={columnDefs} />
      </AgGridReact>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Table;
```

and the following **columns** component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { AgGridColumn } from 'ag-grid-react';

const Columns = ({ columnDefs }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {columnDefs.map((column) => {
        return (
          <AgGridColumn
            headerName={column.headerName}
            field={column.field}
          />
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default Columns;
```

In the code above the columns component is not executed.
When rendering the columns directly in the table component it works and the columns are rendered.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import 'ag-grid-enterprise';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';

const Table = (props) => {
  const [columnDefs, setColumnDefs] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/api/grid/getDataOverviewGrid')
      .then((result) => {
        return result.json();
      })
      .then((gridOverview) => {
        setColumnDefs(gridOverview.data.gridColumns);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="ag-theme-alpine">
      <AgGridReact
        getDataPath={(data) => data.orgHierarchie}
        pagination={true}
        onGridReady={(params) => {
          fetch('/api/grid/getDataOverviewGridRows')
            .then((result) => {
              return result.json();
            })
            .then((rowData) => {
              params.api.setRowData(rowData.data);
            });
        }}
      >
         {columnDefs.map((column) => {
            return (
              <AgGridColumn
                headerName={column.headerName}
                field={column.field}
              />
            );
          })}
      </AgGridReact>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Table;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember where I've read it - apparently not in the documentation - but if `<AgGridReact />` has any children, all of them must be of `<AgGridColumn />`.

Wrapping them in Fragments will most likely not work. Not even `null`s will do (learned that the hard way).